# How do you cancel print job in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, printing

In 13.04 I no longer get the print icon in the taskbar. I have to go through System Settings>Printers>Jobs to see my print queue. But there is no way to cancel the job there. Pressing the stop button does nothing and right-clicking on the job does not give an option to delete. How do you cancel jobs aside from opening a terminal and typing cancel -a? That deletes ALL jobs, which is not helpful if I want to cancel a specific print job.

Comment: Have CUPS handle it: http://localhost:631/jobs/

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Printer icon in System settings. Highlight the printer. Right click to scroll to View Print Queue. Highlight the print job you want to delete. press delete.